# Forgot to add Primary Keys

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

I have duplicated (copied) a table and for some reason Primary Keys wasnt added.
Now I have a lot of new records were added recently with 0 value in the `id` field. All the previous records does have a unique ID (from 1 to 302979).

How to fix this?

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

`AUTO_INCREMENT` wasnt added as well.

```
CREATE TABLE `result` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Can you please post result of `show create table ...` of your table?

Comment: +1, that's really the problem. Does juergen d post helped you? If so, I think my answer is to be deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
update result
inner join (select @row := (select max(id) from result)) r
set id = (@row := @row + 1)
where id = 0
```

to correct the wrong `id`s.

then add `auto_increment` to your table

```
ALTER TABLE `result` CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ;
```

and then use

```
ALTER TABLE result AUTO_INCREMENT = 1234;
```

in which you replace `1234` with the  number you want to start your increment value. It can be the highest id + 1 for instance. You could get that number with

```
select max(id)+1 from result;
```

Comment: This did not work `ALTER TABLE result AUTO_INCREMENT = (select max(id)+1 from result);`

Answer (score 0):

You can export the table to SQL script file. Than you have to create table with key. And then run impoRt again. You should set auto increment property to be true. Not sure whether this is the easiest way, but it's not so hard to do that.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE an empty copy of your table:

```
CREATE TABLE `result_copy` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Add index and autoincrement to this new table:
    ALTER TABLE `result_copy` CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ;

Insert data: (change the ordering if necessary)

```
INSERT INTO `result_copy`(status, status_date, member_id)
SELECT status, status_date, member_id FROM `result`
ORDER BY `id` ASC, `status_date` ASC
```

Check the data in `result_copy`. If everything is fine, remove the original table and rename the new table:

```
DROP TABLE `result`;
RENAME TABLE `result_copy` TO `result`;
```